# Find min value in group and don't count 0s as values if there're other values also in the same group in Excel

Tags: excel, group-by, min

I need to find min year values in each group (grouping factor is ID). When there's only year values "0" in a group, the min result will be "0" but when there are other year values also (e.g. 1997, 0, 2002) then I need to omit the "0" and find the next min (in this example it would have been 1997, not 0).

For example if I have this data:

```
ID      year    
170946  1960    
170946  1960    
170950  0       
170950  0       
170952  1905    
435041  1990    
435041  1995    
435046  0       
435046  1995    
435046  2002
```

Then I want that the new column would look like this:

```
ID      year    MIN
170946  1960    1960
170946  1960    1960
170950  0       0
170950  0       0
170952  1905    1905
435041  1990    1990
435041  1995    1990
435046  0       1995
435046  1995    1995
435046  2002    1995
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Can't you delete the zero data, or substitute them by an apostrophe (')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula in C2

`=MIN(IF(A$2:A$100=A2,IF(B$2:B$100<>0,B$2:B$100)))`

confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copy down

see below

[image]

Comment: It worked but not before I had confirmed it. What confirming does by the way?

Comment: It set up the formula as an "array formula". If you look at the formula editing bar, it adds the `{ }` at the beginning and at the end of the formula (which wouldn't work if you typed them and pressed a single `Enter`. It only works this way!

Answer (score 0):

You must use a array formula with `IF`, `MIN` and `SMALL`, like this:

```
=SMALL(IF(A:A=A2,B:B),IF(MIN(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))=0,2,1))
```

Attempt to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` instead of a single `Enter`.